# Taylor expansion of $Ei(x)$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, approximations, regularization

I'm reading a note on regularization by Muruyama, link http://hitoshi.berkeley.edu/230A/regularization.pdf

On the bottom of page 2, Muruyama Taylor expanded

$$ -\frac{e^{m^2/\Lambda^2}}{4\pi} \operatorname{Ei}(-m^2/\Lambda^2) $$

to get

$$ \frac{1}{4\pi}\left[\left(\ln \frac{\Lambda^2}{m^2}-\gamma\right)+\frac{m^2}{\Lambda^2}\left(2\ln \frac{\Lambda^2}{m^2}+\gamma+1\right)+O({\frac{m^4}{\Lambda^4}})\right] $$

I tried to reproduce this result. What I did is Taylor expanding $e^{m^2/\Lambda^2}$ and $\operatorname{Ei}(-m^2/\Lambda^2)$ separately, using

$$ e^{x} = 1 + {x} + \cdots $$

and

$$ \operatorname{Ei}(x) = \gamma + \ln |x| + \sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{x^k}{k\,k!} $$

(I got this from Wikipedia ["Exponential integral"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral))

So,

$$ e^{m^2/\Lambda^2} \approx 1 + m^2/\Lambda^2 $$

and

$$ \operatorname{Ei}(-m^2/\Lambda^2) \approx \gamma + \ln \frac{m^2}{\Lambda^2} - \frac{m^2}{\Lambda^2} $$

What I ended up having is

$$ -\frac{e^{m^2/\Lambda^2}}{4\pi} \operatorname{Ei}(-m^2/\Lambda^2) = \frac{1}{4\pi}\left[\left(\ln \frac{\Lambda^2}{m^2}-\gamma\right)+\frac{m^2}{\Lambda^2}\left(\ln \frac{\Lambda^2}{m^2}-\gamma+1\right)+ O({\frac{m^4}{\Lambda^4}})\right] $$

Why does my result differ from Maruyama's at $O(m^2/\Lambda^2)$?

Comment: You are right! Mathematica also obtain the same result.

Comment: Most likely a typo in the lecture notes.